# The largest Q&A site for FPGA developers

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I work with Xilinx' s FPGA and I often have different questions. I search for answers on sites like xilinx.com, Stack Overflow, [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/), etc.

I wanted to know of there is a specialized portal for FPGA developers in a format like Stack Overflow, apart from xilinx.com or Electrical Engineering.

Comment: What's wrong with EE? What are you looking for that's not covered by either SO or EE?

Comment: @Mat At present i work with Virtex-5 (GTP/GTX transeivers, Aurora Lane, PCI-E Endpoint Block) and at the request of virtex 5 I receive only 21 posts.

Comment: @KuchurAndrei That means there is a potential community of FPGA developers who have not yet found [electronics.se]. Why don't you invite your friends/colleagues to the site and start participating? The more content that there is, the more people might find the site and join in.

Comment: @AsheeshR Good idea. I think, that so there aren't enough questions because this sphere very specialized. For creation of a simple thing in is necessary to read a lo of datasheets, everyone on 100 pages :)

Comment: @MeNoTalk I had the same feeling when i came to work :)

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50195/embedded-systems

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fwiw, I am an electrical engineer having worked with software and hardware.

I think this is a very good question because there are many FPGA developers around. But I think it would be better to integrate this subdomain into an existing hardware related SE site, and the aforementioned EE seems like a good fit for that to me.

I personally believe it would attract less people on its own, which could be a potential loss for the community that would be built around it. It is a bit like separating a programming language out of Stack Overflow in my personal opinion.

It seems that the EE site already has many questions existing in the following categories (i.e. tags) which are FPGA related:

- fpga
- xilinx
- altera
- vhdl
- verilog

So, my personal two cents is that just try to integrate into a hardware related community, e.g. Electrical Engineering or something else if that does not work out for some reason. Give it a try and see how it goes. :-)